# What is Rocket Lab Electron's dry mass?

Tags: mass, rocketlab, electron

Does anyone know how heavy Rocket Lab's Electron rocket is without fuel? Or do you by chance have any information about the fuel capacity of the first and second stage? I'm trying to model its flight profile but can't find any information about how much fuel it carries.

Separate numbers on first and second stage would be optimal!

Comment: https://flightclub.io might have some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Rocket Lab's user guide, the kick stage weighs 40 kg dry and the fairing weighs 44 kg, and the second stage contains 2000 kg of fuel.

Then I found this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLab/wiki/vehicles/) describing parameters about the Electron, citing the first stage weighing 950 kg and the second stage weighing 250 kg.

According to the Flightclub.io simulation of A Data With Destiny, the second stage weighs 296 kg and the first stage weighs 950 kg.

I hope this clarifies things but take this with a grain of salt as I don't exactly know if these values are accurate.